# NaN result returned from JavaScript function where 'undefined' expected

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript program (shown at the end of this question entry) is producing the following unexpected output:

```
Adding 12 to 5: NaN
```

I'm using Node.js (version 14.16.0) on a Windows 10 machine via a Cygwin command line shell. Here is the source code I'm running (using the command 'node my_program.js'). The output is showing in the Cygwin command line (where console.log is directed to):

```
function my_function(x) {

    return x + z;

    var z = 12;

}

console.log("Adding 12 to 5: " + my_function(5));
```

It was my understanding that the declaration of the z variable would be hoisted to the top of the function block (effectively), but not the initial definition of 12 being assigned to it yet. That would make the initial value of z 'undefined'. Yet when the program runs, a NaN is the result of x + z.

Any help understanding this behavior is appreciated.

Comment: `undefined` plus somthing is `NaN` (not a number). please see `Number(undefined)`.

Comment: Ok yes, that makes more sense. So the initial value of z is in fact 'undefined' as I was expecting. But when the statement 'x + z' gets evaluated, JavaScript casts it to a type Nan (a number + an undefined).

Comment: typeof `NaN` is number.

Comment: Z is undefined ,when we add undefined to anumber it always return not a number(NaN).